# How to remove Private Key Password from pkcs12 container?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

1. I extracted certificate using Chrome's SSL/export command.
2. Then provided it as input to openvpn - in the config for openvpn:
   `pkcs12 "path/to/pkcs12_container"`
3. When calling `openvpn ~/openvp_config` it asks for a password for private key (wich I entered when exporting using Chrome):
   `Enter Private Key Password:...`
4. I want to remove this password request.

*The question: how to remove the password for private key from pkcs12?*

That is, create pkcs12 file which doesn't require a password.

(seems that I already somehow did this a year ago, and now forgot it.damn.)

Comment: the following script does this (essentially it is zero0 answer): https://gist.github.com/5nizza/7ae9cff0d43f33818a33 usage: `./remove_pass_from_cert.sh YourCertName YourCertPass`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It can be achieved by various `openssl` calls.

- PASSWORD is your current password
- YourPKCSFile is the file you want to convert
- NewPKCSWithoutPassphraseFile is the target file for the PKCS12 without passphrase

First, extract the certificate:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -legacy -in "YourPKCSFile" \
      -out certificate.crt -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD
```

Second, the CA key:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -cacerts -nokeys -legacy -in "YourPKCSFile" \
      -out ca-cert.ca -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD
```

Now, the private key:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -legacy -in "YourPKCSFile" \
      -out private.key -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD \
      -passout pass:TemporaryPassword
```

Now remove the passphrase:

```
$ openssl rsa -legacy -in private.key -out "NewKeyFile.key" \
      -passin pass:TemporaryPassword
```

Put things together for the new PKCS-File:

```
$ cat "NewKeyFile.key"  \
      "certificate.crt" \
      "ca-cert.ca" > PEM.pem
```

And create the new file:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -CAfile ca-cert.ca \
      -in PEM.pem -out "NewPKCSWithoutPassphraseFile"
```

Now you have a new PKCS12 key file without passphrase on the private key part.

Comment: awesome answer! ..what is `ca-cert.ca`?

Comment: @Ayrat: This is the CA certificate part of your key. -- I have a typo in the answer, correcting... -- feel free to upvote and accept the answer after you tried it :-)

Comment: `-nodes` is ignored when `-export` is used, it's not documented for this case (see openssl man page, `-nodes` is only listed when exporting from PKCS#12 to PEM). Your last call still prompts me for an export password. And If I just hit return, I get a PKCS#12 file whose password is an empty string and not one without a password. When I then do `openssl pkcs12 -in "NewPKCSWithoutPassphraseFile"` it still prompts me for an import password. I can just hit return and that works but if there was no password, it wouldn't even prompt.

Comment: At the first step I get ```Error outputting keys and certificates
4017F33E857F0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:../crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:349:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()
```. Any ideas?

Comment: @pihentagy: _recent_ OpenSSL (3.0.0 up, since 2021 which is 8 years after this A) by default doesn't support the now-obsolete algorithm RC2-40 which was used in most PKCS12 files before about 2020 and still by some software that hasn't been updated; to read such a file you need to add `-legacy`.

Comment: Chiming in... newer versions of SSL removed older insecure algorithms. Use the -legacy flag to that has no key pair value

Answer (score 55):

The simplest solution [I've found](http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2010/03/remove-the-passphrase-from-a-pkcs12-certificate/) is

#### Export to temporary pem file

```
openssl pkcs12 -in protected.p12 -nodes -out temp.pem
#  -> Enter password
```

#### Convert pem back to p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in temp.pem  -out unprotected.p12
# -> Just press [return] twice for no password
```

#### Remove temporary certificate

```
rm temp.pem
```

Comment: I don't see a downside to this approach.

Comment: Some tools require a password. For example `keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore unprotected.p12` will emit a warning and will NOT list the certificate. So it may work for OpenVPN, but not for something else.

Comment: @mivk what do you mean? That some tools require a password protected key?

Comment: @Koen : yes. Apparently, `keytool` (and probably other Java applications?) refuses to list certs in a pkcs12 container which was created with an empty export password. But I understand that OpenVPN doesn't care. So it just means: if you made it with an empty password, check that it actually works in your application.

Comment: Sure, but the question is about removing the password, not about applications that require a password to be set.

Comment: Your solution doesn't create a PKCS#12 w/o a password but one with a password that is "" (emtpy string), which is not the same.

Answer (score 11):

This can easily be done in one step with no temporary file:

`openssl pkcs12 -in "PKCSFile" -nodes | openssl pkcs12 -export -out "PKCSFile-Nopass"`

Answer the Import Password prompt with the password.
Answer the Export Passowrd prompts with <CR>

Done.

Note that this handles any number of intermediate certificates that may be in the bundle...

I strongly recommend taking care with the resulting file; it would be a good idea to set umask to 377 first (non-unix: this means only owner can read file that's created.)  I suppose that's 2 steps, if your default umask is permissive...

Comment: I see: 'Enter Import Password:' and 'MAC verified OK' but then 'unable to load certificates'. This is an Apple p12 file - maybe they're different.

Comment: This creates a P12 with EMPTY password which is not the same as NO password. And if only works if the input file has the key bag before the cert bag, which varies depending on what sw created it and how; otherwise you get the error @TimBaverstock did.

Comment: If you're using openssl 3 or above and you find problems, you may have to add the `-legacy` flag at the first command as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72600724/955619

Answer (score 2):

Now, the private key:

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "YourPKCSFile" -out private.key -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD -passout pass:TemporaryPassword
```

Remove now the passphrase:

```
openssl rsa -in private.key -out "NewKeyFile.key" -passin pass:TemporaryPassword
```

The 2 steps may be replaced by

```
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "YourPKCSFile" -out private.key -nodes
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately none of the answers posted thus far are correct, as they just supply a blank password as opposed to no password, which means that you will still get prompted for a password in the first place.

For the sake of keeping everything together in one place, I'll copy @slm's post with some slight ammendments;

- PASSWORD is your current password
- YourPKCSFile is the file you want to convert
- NewPKCSWithoutPassphraseFile is the target file for the PKCS12 without passphrase

First, extract the certificate:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -in "YourPKCSFile" -out certificate.crt \
    -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD
```

Second, the CA (issuer) certificate:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -cacerts -nokeys -in "YourPKCSFile" -out ca-cert.ca \
    -password pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD
```

Now, the private key:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -in "YourPKCSFile" -out private.key -password \
    pass:PASSWORD -passin pass:PASSWORD -passout pass:TemporaryPassword
```

Now remove the passphrase:

```
$ openssl rsa -in private.key -out "NewKeyFile.key" -passin pass:TemporaryPassword
```

Put things together for the new PKCS-File:

Bash:

```
$ cat "NewKeyFile.key" "certificate.crt" "ca-cert.ca" > PEM.pem
```

CMD:

```
$ type "NewKeyFile.key" "certificate.crt" "ca-cert.ca" > PEM.pem
```

And create the new file:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -nodes -CAfile ca-cert.ca -in PEM.pem
    -out "NewPKCSWithoutPassphraseFile.p12" -passout pass:
```

Comment: This avoids the prompting but it still uses an empty password.; the way to have NO password is `-certpbe NONE -keypbe NONE -nomac`. As already noted you can use `-nodes` on step 3 and skip step 4; you can also combine steps 1 and 2 as `pkcs12 -nokeys >bothcerts` and then just do `pkcs12 -export -in bothcerts -inkey key` without needing either `cat` or `type` to combine the files.

Answer (score 2):

My use-case was to remove a password from a `.p12` file for fastlane. I tried all the answers from this thread, but then I stumbled upon [some blog post](https://medium.com/@danqiang/use-your-existing-certificates-in-fastlane-match-ios-be520831f3b5) that had the answer that worked finally for me.

1. Import your `.p12` file to your Keychain Access. You can do it simply by double-clicking the file. You'll be prompted with the password to the private key. Enter it.
2. Export this certificate as both `.cer` and `.p12`. When prompted for `.p12` password, confirm empty text field.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure PowerShell solution that works without OpenSSL:

```perl
Install-Module -Name 'Carbon.Cryptography'
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString
$cert = Get-CCertificate -Path PATH -Password $password -KeyStorageFlags Exportable
[IO.File]::WriteAllBytes(OUT_PATH, $cert.Export('Pfx'))
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me. In the end I reverted to dotNet code which worked first time.

```
class Script
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
                if (args.Length < 3 || args.Contains("/?"))
                {
                    MainHelp(args);
                    return;
                }
       string _infile = args[0],
                        _outfile = args[2];
                string _password = args[1], _outpassword = (args.Length > 3) ? args[3] : "";
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} -> {1} with ({2} -> {3})", _infile, _outfile, _password, _outpassword));
                System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert = null;
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Load {0} with {2}", _infile, _outfile, _password, _outpassword));
                cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(_infile, _password, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Export {1} with {3}", _infile, _outfile, _password, _outpassword));
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_outfile, cert.Export(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType.Pfx, _outpassword));
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Export complete", _infile, _outfile, _password, _outpassword));
    }

     static public void MainHelp(string[] args)
    {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage pfxremovepwd [inpfx] [inpwd] [outpfx] [optional outpwd]");
            return;
    }
}
```